# Refresh console (not changing previous output) (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console, refresh

I'm developing a program in c++.

It outputs several times the character 219: █

When I output several 219-chars█, there is a small space between them, and I would like to make it so that no space appears between those chars.

After having outputed the characters, this is what I see (3 blue characters):
[image: catura1]

However, if I change the size of the window, the characters display correctly (using the whole space):
[image: captura2]

I guess there must be a way to tell the console to update its contents, its buffer, or something like that, so that characters are displayed correctly.

I've tried:

```
HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD bufferSize = {140, 50}; //140 and 50, the original values. So that the buffer size is not modified
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(handle, bufferSize);
```

hoping it would "refresh" the buffer.... But I couldn't display the chars as I wanted.

Some time ago I read something about a function to refresh the console output, but I don't remember how it was, and I can't find it after some hours googling it.

If some one could tell me how to display the chars correctly I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that how much space is between the characters depends only on the size of the console window and the size of the font.  Printing spaces and changing the background color (via WriteConsoleOutputAttribute) might work better.